# how to hide a pre-filter window in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm looking for a way how to hide a pre-filter in CRM 2011.

I created a sipmle report by using business intelligent studio. 
Eventially, the reports shows a table with data (SQL query like select column1, column2....from table)

when I open it in CRM I get a window where I have to built filter.

Is there any way avoid such window?

I found that I cand set a query in filter by default but anyway It doesn't help except this screen
[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the pre-filter page, you have to remove the corresponding **Report Parameter** in the RDL report, which is named as *CRMFilteredEntityName*, e.g. CRM_FilteredAccount.