# Disable / Enable prefiltering in dynamics crm 2011

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I've created a report. on loading the report in dynamics CRM there is an option for "Edit Filter", by using this the user can edit the filters accordingly and the whole report results can be changed in the similar ways.

So, Is there any mean to disable the Edit Filter button?

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231532/how-to-hide-a-pre-filter-window-in-crm-2011/16232028#16232028

Comment: I want to fetch the records for a specific record like an account name is "ABC" and i want to get the records related to this account on related form. Then how could be this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hi its just additional filter on your query, its used before the query is run. And default is empty filter, i dont see any meaning in disabling unless you want the users to only see the one fixed report.

Are you using online or onpremis ?

Comment: I am using it on online account.